# problem getting my python script to work an to call my variable

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am building a python script for a pipe class and define some variables in the main script and made an executable script that calls the main script and gives value to an area with a true or false logic to determine if there is a need for an area or not. I do not know much about python and will indeed appreciate any help with this. I will include the part of my scripts that relate to the problem mentioned.

```
#this is the main program 

import numpy as np
import sys

uCounter = 0

class Pipe(object):
   global uCounter

   def __init__(self, nPorts, volume):
      self.volume = volume
      self.rhoj = D(1)
      self.Pj = D(1)
      self.nPorts = nPorts  
      self.freePorts = []
      self.portSetm = []  
      self.portSetP = []
      self.portSetValue = []  
      self.portSetAreas = []  
      self.portSetAreasValue = [] 
      for i in range(nPorts):
         self.freePorts.append(i)
         self.portSetm.append(False)
         self.portSetP.append(False)
         self.portSetValue.append(0.0)
         self.portSetAreas.append(False)
         self.portSetAreasValue.append(0.0)
      self.m = D(self.nPorts)
      self.P = D(self.nPorts)
      self.Areas = D(self.nPorts)
      self.pd = np.zeros((self.nPorts))
      self.dt = 0.0  

   def logics(self, freePorts):                                                                                  
      for port in range(nPorts):
         if self.portSetAreas[self.freePorts[port]] != 0:
            self.Areas[port] = self.portSetAreasValue[self.freePorts[port]]

   def Values1(self):
      equation = Equation(1, uCounter)
      for p in range(self.nPorts):
         equation.A[0, self.m.gid[p]] = self.Areas[port]
      equation.c[0] = 0.0
      return(equation)

#and this is the executable 

import math
import numpy as np
import sys
import scipy.io
import mainproject

Pipe1.portSetAreas[0] = True
Pipe1.portSetAreasValue[0] = 0.1
Pipe1.portSetAreas[1] = True
Pipe1.portSetAreasValue[1] = 0.1

#0 refers to the inlet of the pipe
#1 refers to the outlet of the pipe
```

```
equation.A[0,self.m.gid[p]] = self.Areas[port]
NameError: global name 'port' is not defined
```

Comment: for p in range(self.nPorts): equation.A[0, self.m.gid[p]] = self.Areas[port]

change 'p' to 'port'. Or even better 'port' to 'p'.

Comment: I have tried this and I still get an error '    equation.A[0,self.m.gid[p]] = self.Areas[p]
TypeError: 'D' object does not support indexing'

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `p` and not `port` in your for loop.

```
     for p in range(self.nPorts):
         equation.A[0, self.m.gid[p]] = self.Areas[port]
```

That said, you have other logical errors in your code as well.

This code is going to also cause an error:

```
   def logics(self, freePorts):                                                                                  
      for port in range(nPorts):
```

You should likely change your range call to `range(self.nPorts)`.

Comment: I tried it as you suggested and I have a new error    ' equation.A[0,self.m.gid[port]] = self.Areas[port]
TypeError: 'D' object does not support indexing'

Comment: you see this part of the scripts puts the multiple values (each port's area value) in an array. The D refers to a 1 D domain that I have defined in the script and it works fine. my issue just started when I decided that I want to include different areas for each port. 
for p in range(self.nPorts):
         equation.A[0, self.m.gid[p]] = self.Areas[p]